# Do I keep the season pass? if uninstalled?

Tags: fallout-4, ps4

I was wondering if I un-install fallout 4 for the ps4 wil the season pass also be gone? I want to delete some patches and was recomended to do it this way. and will i lose the save games? or do I have to start allover again?

Comment: You should post the second part as a second, separate question. (you can always back up your saves btw)

Comment: As for the save games, they may not be compatible with a lower version if you downgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Your season pass is tied to your account, not your console. Your season pass should still be available once you reinstall in the future.